# Where does facebook take "People have been here" data from?

Tags: facebook

Simple question I cannot find an answer to:

Where and how does facebook get the data for the number of people who "have been" to a place?

Is it all GPS / mobile data?

If you live in a certain location does this contribute to the "been here" number?

It seems the number correspends rather well for cities.

EG
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sofia-Bulgaria/106013482772674
Sofia has about 2m Citizens, and 1,8m "people have been here".

Answer (score 4):

The photos and posts which have location tagged will automatically appear in **People have been here**

exp - If I've been to *Taj Mahal*, and uploaded a photo on Facebook with location *Taj Mahal*, it will contribute 1 to **People have been here** count, and if I also tag 5 of my friends in that post, it will contribute 6 to that count (obviously IFF they haven't included in that count before, by them self, or some one else)

Comment: Non FB User so sry for stupid question but, how does the tagging work do you need to explicitly tag it or does google assume where you are based on your profile address or GPS?

Comment: You can either tag the location yourself or if your camera or mobile phone has geotagging features, then Facebook automatically recognizes the city the picture was taken at (using EXIF data) and provides relevant suggestions.